# Bind image in templated ListBox to ViewModel property

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, mvvm, datatemplate

TL;DR - I had a binding error. Tired eyes miss things.

I have implemented a multi-select CheckBox list using a ListBox as the container. Now, beside each checkbox in the list I want to display an image whose visbility is bound to a ViewModel property, but I'm having difficulty doing this.

My styles are:

```
<Grid.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="ListBoxCheckStyle" TargetType="ListBox">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                            <ItemsPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ListBoxCheckStyleItemsPanelTemplate">
                <StackPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Style x:Key="ListBoxItemCheckStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                                
                                <ChimeControls:CheckBox 
                                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                        Margin="0,0,10,0"
                                        IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                <Image 
                                    Width="16" 
                                    Height="16" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                    Source="{StaticResource OccurredStatusTypeImageSource}" 
                                    Visibility="{Binding HasConsentCondition, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, FallbackValue=Collapsed}" 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                    Margin="10,0,10,0" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
```

My Listbox is defined as:

```
<ListBox 
                                x:Name="objectivesListBox" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                Style="{StaticResource ListBoxCheckStyle}" 
                                ItemsPanel="{StaticResource ListBoxCheckStyleItemsPanelTemplate}" 
                                ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemCheckStyle}"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding ObjectivesList}"
                                DisplayMemberPath="mgt_plan_obj_name"
                                AttachedProperties:ListBoxSelectedItems.Items="{Binding SelectedObjectives, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                SelectionMode="Multiple"/>
```

My image never displays though, and the getter of the property the Visibility is bound to is never called. What am I missing?

Comment: Your XAML looks OK. Are there any binding errors in the Output window during runtime? If you put a breapoint in your `BoolToVisibilityConverter` is it being hit? Is `OccurredStatusTypeImageSource` points to the correct image?

Comment: Gah, I could swear I looked at the output window and there was no binding errors yeaterday. I suppose that's what fresh eyes in the morning brings. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by nemesv, I checked my output window again and there was my binding error.